# How can I anonymously logon to Exchange 2003 SMTP server to send mail?

Tags: smtp, exchange-2003, visualsvn-server

I have anonymous logon enabled on the my Exchange 2003's virtual SMTP server however trying to send emails (using the program VisualSVNServerHooks: http://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00018/), I get a failed to connect error when I dont supply a username and password. The event logs reveal nothing...

How can I anonymously logon to Exchange 2003 SMTP server to send mail?

Unfortunately since nothing is logged by exchange all I have to go by is VisualSVN's error:

```
"E020014: The transport failed to connect to the server"
```

The server is localhost and firewall is not blocking.

Comment: what is wrong with this question??

Comment: I was wondering the same thing. Probably just explain more about your problem solving approach, with snippets of config and logs. You could also use tcpdump/wireshark to see what the traffic was for the "access denied" result.

Comment: I regret adding the VisualSVN details because I just want to know the answer to my original question: "How can I anonymously logon to Exchange 2003 SMTP server to send mail?", regardless of what my be wrong with VisualSVN here.

Comment: Have you tried sending mail without logging in from a normal mail client or directly through telnet? That will remove visualsvn from the equation and possibly give you a more useful error message.

Comment: Are you trying to use your exchange server as an SMTP relay?

Comment: By looking at the visualsvn hooks - you define the smtp server to use: which is your exchange server? That is exactly SMTP-relay.
It means that visualsvn uses your exchange (without auth), to send e-mails.

Answer (score 1):

Applications sending e-mails through your exchange server, should be allowed to relay e-mail messages through your send connectors.

I found this by some googling: [How-To](http://forums.kayako.com/threads/how-to-setup-windows-2003-and-exchange-2003-smtp-relaying.12411/)

The list of allowed IP's in Exchange is empty by default.

Comment: I dont think I want to relay - relay is passing on emails i.e. my exchange would sit between the program and another exchange - I want my program to directly connect to exchange's SMTP and send an email to one of an email address it controls (i.e. in the its address list).

Comment: Relay is not exchange to exchange traffic. We use relay for sending e-mails from both web-apps and other software applications in need of "alerts". If it uses your exchange as an SMTP-Relay, it's no problem sending to addresses in your domain!


One example of use is "Nagios" alerting my address via smtp-relay on our exchange

Dependant on how you configure the relay - it can use only internal addresses if you want but also commonly used for external aswell (to pass PTR checks).